# Как поменять размер определенной кнопки в CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

В CKEDITOR есть кнопка "Размер шрифта". Может, для "Size" ее длина и подошла бы. Но для русского содержимого - нет. 
Вопрос - как грамотно изменить ее ширину? В стилях все минимизировано. Мне кажется, что лезть в стандартный css и менять - это неправильный вариант, что можно и нужно сделать как-то по-другому. Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для таких случаев создают свой css, который подключают позже стандартного. В нем переопределяют стандартные стили.

Answer (score 0):

в папке skins/твой скин/ есть файлы editor.css и еще группа файлов editor_???.css  ищи в них `cke_combo__fontsize .cke_combo_text{width:30px}` .Поменяйте ширину примерно на 80px